# How to divide an array of objects into subarrays more efficiently in Swift?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, performance

I have a Swift app and the following for loop is taking about a second to complete. Is there a way to improve the performance? I could replace `for` loop with 3 `filter` methods but I doubt it's going to help.

```
// metrics.count == 10000
var metricsByStatus: Dictionary<String, Array<HKQuantitySample>> = ["low": [], "high": [], "normal": []]

// HKQuantitySample.status:
func status(low: Double, high: Double) -> String {
    if value < low {
        return "low"
    } else if value > high {
        return "high"
    } else {
        return "normal"
    }
}

// This is taking 1 second, 100% CPU
for metric in metrics {
  metricsByStatus[metric.status(low: limits["low"], high: limits["high"])].append(metric)
}
```

Comment: Does Swift has object (record) type? If so, using a `Dictionary<String, ...>` seems really wasteful (you need dictionary lookup, etc.)

Comment: Similarly for `limits` dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "low", "medium", "high" with enum values.

Extract limits[low], limits[high] once before the loop.

Profile the existing code. You'll find that it spends most of its time comparing strings.

Only measure performance in a release build, not a debug build.

I find `[String: [HKQuantitySample]]` much more readable than `Dictionary<String, Array<HKQuantitySample>>` .